# jquery post json data to PHP file

Tags: json, jquery, post

I have a click event where I compose a **json data**, then I want to **POST it to a PHP file for processing**. But something goes wrong.
My PHP file is simplified for now looking like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

And the code for POST-ing looks like this:

```
// myarray is: var myarray = new Array(); 
// and it gets populated above this code

var strObj = JSON.stringify(myarray);
alert(strObj); // so far I get the alert containing valid JSON text
$.ajax ({
  type:"POST",
  url:"proces.php",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  data: strObj,
  success: function(){ alert("success")},
  error: function(){ alert("error")}
});
```

So when I click the button, I receive the alert containing the JSON string (looks fine), then I get the alert saying "error", and when I check the console for the response of proces.php all I see is:

```
array(0) {
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?** What can I do to make it right?

Comment: I think u need to change header to : header('Content-type: application/json');  (at line 1 of proces.php) (and return valid JSON response)

Comment: I added the header to my php file still nothing new. The response is the same. (I updated the php in the question body)

Comment: echo json_encode($_POST);

Comment: add `console.log(this, arguments);` to error callback and check in console what exact error you get; also you have typo in `success` param name.

Comment: @Tommi I solved the success param issue. Not the real problem. I entered the code manually here (not copy/paste) so it was just a typo.

Comment: About main issue @DarkBee is right, you don't return valid json from server, but notify jquery that dataType is "json"; jQuery throws exception because cannot parse php serialized data. Either encode json on server or set dataType to "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer on my own. Seems to do the trick:

```
$.post("proces.php", {json: JSON.stringify(myarray)}, function(data){alert(data);});
```

I mean, I do not get the alert(data); (probably because I do not return a JSON back from php file) but in the PHP I can see the json data now.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

```
$.ajax ({
  type:"POST",
  url:"proces.php",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  data: {tmp: strObj},
  success: function(){ alert("success")},
  error: function(){ alert("error")}
});
```

Comment: I can't see how, because it does not work for me. My code that works is posted below this. I made it work somehow :)