# not able to pass json data to php via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

This is the following code that I am using.

### Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var stuff = new Object();
    stuff[0] = {'id':'0','value':'no','type':'img','filename':'hehehehe.jpg','filesize':'0.3356 MB','fileformat':'jpg','change':'0','caption':'this is a description about the stuff inserted'};
    stuff[1] = {'id':'1','value':'yes','type':'img','filename':'hehehehe.jpg','filesize':'0.3356 MB','fileformat':'jpg','change':'0','caption':'this is a description about the stuff inserted'};
    stuff[2] = {'id':'2','value':'yes','type':'img','filename':'hsdssssdfhe.jpg','filesize':'0.4356 MB','fileformat':'png','change':'0','caption':'description 2 of the image'};
    stuff[3] = {'id':'3','value':'yes','type':'vid','filename':'hehehehe.mp4','filesize':'56 MB','fileformat':'mp4','change':'0','caption':'this is video'};
    console.log(stuff);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "test1.php",
    data: stuff,
    success: function(data){
        alert('Items added');
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
    });
    </script>
```

### test1.php

```
    <?php
    $arr = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    print_r($arr);
    ?>
```

The console on Chrome shows the object but php shows undefined.. How can I use the json data in PHP??
[image]

Comment: don't you need to jsonencode stuff before you post it as you're just posting an array of json data to php which php obviously can't decode as its an array not a jsonencoded array of json data.

Comment: try with 'var stuff = new Array()' instead of 'var stuff = new Object()';

Comment: A simple google search led me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592173/jquery-post-json-data-to-php-file).

Comment: @anand4tech still same msg 'undefined'

Comment: @anand4tech: try _not_ to use `new` in JS when there is a shorter, more consistent alternative (`var stuff = [];` or `var stuff = {}`)

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem, yes that I know, Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a post parameter called `data` but it is not send

Try

```
data: {
    data: JSON.stringify(stuff)
}
```

Since you are transferring json data look at sending the data as request body like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "test1.php",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(stuff),
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Items added');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

then in server side(not a PHP guy so not sure) using [http-get-request-body](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php)

```
$arr = json_decode(http_get_request_body(), true);
```

Comment: You don't stringify. Look at this question which I just answered a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607905/json-decode-is-not-working-correct/20608260#20608260

Comment: I would refrain from using `http_get_request_body()` since it depends on the PECL extension pecl_http. It's `$_POST['data']` in PHP.

Comment: @user555 haven't used PHP at all... since I was saying about request body just did a google search and copy pasted the code... can you suggest a better solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny Just replace `http_get_request_body()` with `$_POST['data']`.

Comment: @user555 that won't work because it looks for a request parameter called `data` but there are no parameters when we are using request body... we need to read request body as a string... not a request parameter

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh I see. I suppose one could use `file_get_contents('php://input')`, just note this is not the preferred way of doing "it". Once should always try to send request parameters if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Several things are *"wrong"* with your code.
Firstly the JS:

```
stuff = new Object();
```

Now this isn't *wrong* as such, but it's generally recommended *not* to call object constructors like this. You should instead get into the habit of using the literal notations. Seeing as calling constructors may cause unexpected results:

```
var arr = new Array(10);
var arr2 = [10];
console.log(arr2.length);//logs 1, the array looks like this [10]
console.log(arr.length);//logs 10, arr is [undefined, undefined, undefined,...]
//but at the same time:
var arr3 = new Array(1,2);//is identical to:
var arr4 = [1,2];//both create an array containing 2 numbers: [1,2]
```

Same goes for `Object`:

```
var o = new Object();//same as var o = {};
var o2 = new Object('foobar');
console.log(o2);//String {0: 'f', 1: 'o', 2: 'o', ...}
//and so on:
new Object(true);// === new Boolean(true)
new Object(123);// === new Number(123);
```

But you're then using this `Object` as an `Array`!! That doesn't make sense, instead, just write:

```
stuff = [];
//or
stuff = [ {id: 0, ...}];//initialize array from the off
```

JS doesn't complain when you use an object as an array, because arrays *are* instances of `Object`:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype));//Object!
```

An `Array` is an augmented `Object`, basically

Next, the PHP side:

```
$_POST['data'];
```

As I've shown above, you're just sending an array to your PHP script. An array with numeric indexes *does not have a "data" key*. Try:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

And you'll see what you're actually sending to your server.
All in all, what you're actually trying to do, I think is this:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'your.php',
    data: {data: stuff},//send an object, with property data
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);//log the PHP response
    }
});
```

You also seem to be forgetting that AJAX requests are *asynchonous*. The `undefined` that shows up in your console is a JS thing, the result of `console.log`, which returns undefined.
The AJAX request hasn't been performed yet. To see what your request is actually doing, open the *Network* tab (third from the left) in your console. On the bottom, you'll see *XHR* somewhere. Click that, and you should see a POST request go out. You can click on it, and see the headers, the response and what not...

Comment: thanks for such a knowledgeable answer. Im new to this stuff and this will be quite a help.. I changed to `var stuff= {};` and changed the ajax `data:{data: stuff},` and also the php.. it returned `'data' => string '[object Object]'`.. but still not showed the data..

Comment: @Parminder: But `stuff` is used as an array, don't declare it as an object, change it to an array declaration: `var stuff = [];`. The fact that you're getting `[object Object]` tells me that, somewhere down the line, your array of objects is getting coerced to a string, not JSON stringified... Is the code you posted the actual, real, full code?

Comment: yes i've copy pasted the code which i am trying. what should i do make it working? This is my first time with json data..

Comment: @Parminder: Just enlarged your screenshot: PHP isn't showing `undefined`. That's JS. Ajax is _Asynchronous_. Whatever PHP returns, will be dealt with in the `success` or `error` callback functions. You'll have to wait for the server to respond, and add `console.log` statements in the `success` and `error` functions. Add a `console.log(arguments)` statement to both functions, to see what arguments are being passed to those functions, and see if the response you're looking for is one of those arguments...

Comment: @Parminder Your `error` callback function is wrong. There is no `e.message`. `e` returns the `jqXHR` object and it has no property named `message`, therefore your `console.log` outputs `unidentified`.

Comment: Use `json_decode(.., true);` (second param `true`) in your PHP to let it show arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it working.. thnks to all of you for suggestions.. only minor changes..

### JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var stuff = [];   // changed from var stuff = new object();
    stuff[0] = {'id':'0','value':'no','type':'img','filename':'hehehehe.jpg','filesize':'0.3356 MB','fileformat':'jpg','change':'0','caption':'this is a description about the stuff inserted'};
    stuff[1] = {'id':'1','value':'yes','type':'img','filename':'hehehehe.jpg','filesize':'0.3356 MB','fileformat':'jpg','change':'0','caption':'this is a description about the stuff inserted'};
     stuff[2] = {'id':'2','value':'yes','type':'img','filename':'hsdssssdfhe.jpg','filesize':'0.4356 MB','fileformat':'png','change':'0','caption':'description 2 of the image'};
     stuff[3] = {'id':'3','value':'yes','type':'vid','filename':'hehehehe.mp4','filesize':'56 MB','fileformat':'mp4','change':'0','caption':'this is video'};
     console.log(stuff);
    var a = JSON.stringify(stuff);  //this is required otherwise it sends the object to php rather JSON string.
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "test1.php",
    data: a,
    success: function(data){

    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e.responseText);   //changed from e.message no message argument in error response . thanks to @user555 valuable suggestion
    }
    });
    </script>
```

### test1.php

```
    <?php  $data = $_POST['data'];
    $arr = json_decode($data, true);
    echo $arr[3]['type'];
    ?>
```

The output is `vid` in console. It is properly returning the array value. It will show the result in the console. This is a working example, anyone can copy and paste for exploring more. It has helped me a lot, it will definitely help you too..